# Is it possible to "copy" an object whose templated class derives from a non-templated base?

Tags: c++, class, templates, polymorphism

I've built a small, limited-scope, cross-platform UI library in C++. It uses the following classes to handle UI callbacks:

```cpp
// Base class for templated __Callback class to allow for passing __Callback
// objects as parameters, storing in containers, etc. (as Callback*)
class Callback
{
    public:
        virtual void execute() = 0;
        virtual ~Callback() { }

    protected:
        Callback() { }
};
```

As the comment describes, this is the base class for callbacks - which allows for passing them as arguments and storing them inside UI widgets such that the proper callback can be executed (when, for example, a user clicks a button).

```cpp
// C++ has no callbacks (in the sense of an action [method] of a
// target [object]), so we had to roll our own. This class can be used
// directly, but the NEW_CALLBACK macro is easier.
template <class __TargetType>
class __Callback : public Callback
{
    public:
        typedef __TargetType TargetType;
        typedef void (TargetType::*ActionType)(void);

        virtual void execute()
        {
            (this->__target->*this->__action)();
        }

        __Callback(TargetType* target_, ActionType action_) :
        Callback(), __target(target_), __action(action_) { }

        virtual ~__Callback() { }

    private:
        // target object for the callback
        TargetType* __target;

        // action (method) of the target that will be called
        ActionType __action;
};
```

This templated class is the meat of the callback paradigm. It stores a pointer to an object and a pointer to a member function, such that the member function can be called on the target object at a later time.

```cpp
#define NEW_CALLBACK(class_, obj_, act_) \
    new __Callback<class_>(obj_, &class_::act_)
```

This macro just makes it a little easier to create a templated `__Callback` object.

This has been working great for a long while! A button with a callback might be instantiated like:

```cpp
MyClass* obj = new MyClass();
Button* btn = new Button("Title", NEW_CALLBACK(MyClass, obj, btnClicked));
```

This would create a button, to be placed in a window or other container at a later time, and when clicked it will call `obj->btnClicked()`.

**Now, my question** (sorry for the lengthy setup, I don't think I could pare it down any more than this). A case has arisen where I need to copy a `Callback*` object. Of course, since it's just a pointer to the base class, I can't determine the type of the templated derived class.

**How would one go about copying an arbitrary `Callback` object, with the copy pointing to the same target and action as the original?** Or, is there an entirely different approach to this callback problem that I should be taking (though I would prefer not to change it too much)?

Thanks all!

Comment: Is the type erasure a strict requirement on `Callback`? Unrelated: Two leading underscores in identifiers are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Holy crap, please absolutely refrain from naming your types and variables like that! Any identifier with double underscore (`__this` or `even__this`) or leading underscore + capital letter (`_This`) is reserved for the implementation, and it kinda feels like you're doubly breaking that rule.

Comment: I didn't realize this convention/limitation existed, thanks for pointing it out. I have been utilizing double-underscore prefixes for private members, single for protected members, and none for public. Similarly, single underscore suffixes for arguments and double for return-by-reference. My example is simplified; the real source code for this project is scoped inside a couple namespaces, and most identifiers are prefixed with a project code (e.g. "__abcMember"). In any event, do you have a good link for describing this limitation + any scoping considerations, etc?

Comment: @inspector-g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: Namespaces and scoping are irrelevant, since macros completely ignore them. If the implementation defines a macro that unexpectedly has the same name as your members or anything, you're in trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better approach that you should take, but this seems like an ideal use for a clone method.

You simply need to define a copy constructor in your __Callback template, define a pure virtual Clone method in your base class, and then implement that virtual method in your template (making use of the copy constructor that you've created)

For example:

```
class Callback
{
    public:
    ...
    virtual Callback* Clone()=0;
};

template <class __TargetType>
class __Callback : public Callback
{
public:
    ...
    __Callback(const __Callback& other) :
        __target(other.target_), __action(other.action_) { }

    virtual Callback* Clone()
    {
        return new __Callback(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The `clone()` method is clever; wish I'd thought of it :)

Comment: @inspector-g - it's called a "prototype".  Grab the GoF book.

Answer (score 1):

Use [clone](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8) as a replacement for virtual constructors. Notice the
co-variant return types that make this really work. e.g.

```
struct Callback {
  virtual Callback* clone() const;
};

template<...>
struct Callback_impl {
  virtual Callback_impl* clone() const;
};
```

You should also think about `shared_ptr` for lifetime management. All
this seems a little fragile.

To me it looks like you want [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) . It is polymorphic, type-safe and works with pointers to member functions through `std::mem_fn`.

Comment: Thanks for the link and bit of code! Both answers have been helpful, but, as they say, there can be only one. In regards to `shared_ptr`, I couldn't agree more. I have been reading about them and similar paradigms lately, but haven't used them. As this project is so far along, I recently decided to toy around with them for a bit outside of it to familiarize myself and then utilize them in a subsequent version.

Comment: I added something I thought about this morning.